# Is a lambda expression something more than an anonymous inner class with a single method?

Tags: java, programming-languages, lambda, closures

There is a new hype with the long awaited lambda expressions in Java 8; every 3 day another article appears with them about how cool they are.

As far as I have understood a lambda expression is nothing more than an anonymous inner class with a single method (at least at the byte-code level). Besides this it comes with another nice feature - type inference but I believe the equivalent of this can be achieved with generics on some level (of course not in such a neat way as with lambda expressions).

Knowing this, are lambda expressions going to bring something more than just a syntactic sugaring in Java? Can I create more powerful and flexible classes or other object-oriented constructs with lambda expressions that aren't possible to be built with current language features?

Comment: When a language is turing-complete, **every** added feature could theoretically be described as "syntactic sugar".

Comment: @Philipp: That's wrong. The defining characteristic of syntactic sugar is that desugaring is purely local and does not change the global structure of the program. There are lots of features that cannot be implemented with just local transformations. For example, if you take a hypothetical language that is identical to Java but with proper tail calls, it would not be possible to desugar tail calls to "pure" Java without globally transforming the entire program.

Comment: @Philipp: Unfortunately there is only one upvote for comments, otherwise I would upvote Joerg's comment 1000 times. No, it is wrong that any feature can be described as syntactic sugar. Syntactic sugar does not add new semantics. In fact, AFAIK the proposed Java lambdas are NOT syntactic sugar for special anonymous inner classes because they have different semantics.

Comment: @Giorgio: and what different semantics do they have?

Comment: They differ at least in the way they treat the `this` keyword: in an anonymous inner class it refers to the anonymous instance itself, in a lambda it refers to the surrounding object (see e.g. http://doanduyhai.wordpress.com/2012/07/12/java-8-lambda-in-details-part-ii-scoping-of-this-and-effectively-final-variable-semantic/, line 17 of the snippet). Introducing lambdas as pure syntactic sugar on top of anonymous inner classes was one of the lambda proposals (actually, my favourite one), but another proposal was preferred, which introduces different semantics.

Comment: @Giorgio: Yes, but the conversion of `this` into `OuterClass.this` is part of the process of de-sugaring lambda expressions into anonymous class.

Comment: And what is the syntax for the old semantics? I mean, how does a lambda refer to itself it `this` is used for the surrounding object?

Comment: @Giorgio: a lambda can't refer to itself internally. A lambda is a  more restricted special case of anonymous classes. For example, an anonymous class can have instance variables to store state across calls, and a lambda can't. So lambdas can't do everything that anonymous classes can. But anonymous classes can do everything that lambdas can.

Comment: @user102008: Well, then maybe you are right that the semantics is a restriction of that of an anonymous inner-class, and that the `this` syntax has been reassigned to a different meaning. As a side observation: "For example, an anonymous class can have instance variables to store state across calls, and a lambda can't.": this seems a bit unusual to me since many languages that traditionally support closures (e.g. SML, scheme) do allow internal variables which can be used exactly to store (and hide) state inside the closure.

Comment: See also my answer that addresses the syntactic sugar question, though it's an answer to a different question: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/181743/59134

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**tl;dr:** while it's *mostly* syntactic sugar, that nicer syntax makes lots of things practical that used to end in endless, unreadable lines of braces and parentheses.

Well, it's actually the other way around as lambdas are **much** older than Java. Anonymous inner classes with a single method are (were) the closest Java came to lambdas. It's an approximation that was "good enough" for some time, but has a very nasty syntax.

On the surface, Java 8 lambdas seem to be not much more than syntactic sugar, but when you look below the surface, you see tons of interesting abstractions. For example the JVM spec treats a lambda quite differently from a "true" object, and while you can *handle* them as if they where objects, the JVM is not required to implement them as such.

But while all that technical trickery is interesting and relevant (since it allows future optimizations in the JVM!), the *real* benefit is "just" the syntactic sugar part.

What's easier to read:

```
myCollection.map(new Mapper<String,String>() {
  public String map(String input) {
    return new StringBuilder(input).reverse().toString();
  }
});
```

or:

```
myCollection.map(element -> new StringBuilder(element).reverse().toString());
```

or (using a method handle instead of a lambda):

```
myCollection.map(String::toUpperCase);
```

The fact that you can finally express in a concise way which would previously be 5 lines of code (of which 3 are utterly boring) brings a real change of what is *practical* (but not of what is possible, granted).

Comment: I totally agree with the syntax sugaring part; my question was about new object-oriented constructs only possible with lambda expressions; after all Java is an object-oriented language. Think in comparison with generics, and how they bought much flexibility in Java, flexibility unachievable without them.

Comment: @m3th0dman: actually generics added no new abilities. A `List` could hold any object, a `List<String>` can "only" hold strings. Generics added a *restriction* (and the option to formalize restrictions!), not an addition in power. Pretty much everything since Java 1.1 has been syntactic sugar. And that's not necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: @m3th0dman: Actually generics added no new abilities, because in Java they are just a syntactic sugar. A `List<String>` is just a `List` with cast to `String` added around some return values. Nevertheless they are extremely useful and made the language much more convenient to write in. Lambdas are similar case.

Comment: Actually it's far more than just syntactic sugar.  Much of the functionality is implemented as a first class citizen in the JVM through use of the invokedynamic bytecode + some pretty hefty advances to the Type inference system.  It's not implemented as anonymous inner classes.

Comment: @JanHudec: well, they are slightly more than syntactic sugar, because the *compiler* actually respects them. The *runtime* doesn't care about them, that's true.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Can you point to further reading for this: `For example the JVM spec treats a lambda quite differently from a "true" object...`?

Comment: @zengr: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27524543/2711488), for example. From that perspective, they *are* true objects, but a lambda expression is not an instantiation expression. It’s just a request to get an appropriate object in whatever way. From the language’s perspective, lambda expressions are not objects, but something that will be converted to an instance of the target type in a JRE implementation specific way.

Answer (score 15):

For Java, yes, it's nothing more than a better way of creating an anonymous inner class. This is because of the fundamental decision in java that every bit of byte code has to live within a specific class, which cannot be changed now after decades of legacy code to consider.

However, that is not what lambda expressions really are about. In formalisms where they are native concepts rather than a jump-on-the-bandwagon contortion, lambdas are fundamental building blocks; both their syntax and people's attitude towards them are very different. The example of an anonymous recursive function created purely out of lambdas in *Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs* is capable of changing your entire conception of computation. (However, I'm pretty certain that way of learning to program is just to esoteric ever to become a mainstream success story.)

Comment: Learning that everything can be implemented in terms of lambdas is very instructive and not "esoteric" in my opinion. (However, I guess most "coders" don't care about interesting CS theory.) That doesn't mean that lambdas is special; it just means that lambdas are one type of universal construct. There are others, like SKI combinators. Lambdas are fundamental building blocks in functional paradigms, but maybe something else can be fundamental in another paradigm.

Comment: +1 for "jump-on-the-bandwagon contortion": I often wonder why some languages keep changing to mimic other popular languages and why programmers put up with it. I like lambdas and use them a lot in Scala, Lisp, Haskell, but in Java or C++ they feel like an afterthought bolted onto the language just because they have become popular in other languages.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is just a syntactic sugar, in the sense that anywhere you write a lambda, you can re-write that expression as an anonymous inner class expression with one method, where the class implements the functional interface inferred for the lambda's context, and it would be *exactly* equivalent semantically. And you can do this by simply replacing the lambda expression with the anonymous class expression, without changing any other expression or line of code.

Comment: why downvote? what I said is completely correct

Comment: What you write sounds a reasonable proposal for Java lambdas but this proposal was discarded in favour of a different one (http://doanduyhai.wordpress.com/2012/07/12/java-8-lambda-in-details-part-ii-scoping-of-this-and-effectively-final-variable-semantic/).

Comment: @Giorgio: I am not "proposing" anything. What, exactly, do you disagree with what I said? Yes, the inside of the expression will look different, e.g. we will add a method, and yes, `this` will need to be converted to `OuterClass.this`. That does not contradict what I said -- every lambda *expression* can be converted into a semantically-equivalent anonymous class *expression* without altering anything *outside of that expression*. I didn't say that the inside wouldn't change.

Comment: I am not saying that you are proposing something, there were different proposals for Java8 lambdas, and one was chosen.

Comment: What you said is incorrect. The semantics of lambda and anon inner classes are not **exactly** the same (though they are similar). Off the top of my head, the meaning of meaning of *this* changes; and anon inner classes *always* result in a new instance of an object, whereas a lambda might or might not.

Comment: @StuartMarks: No, you didn't read my answer. I didn't say that each of them can do everything the other does. I said that a lambda has an equivalent anonymous class that is semantically the same. As I already said in comments, `this` in lambda is a part of the syntactic sugar, and is not a difference in semantics. And about differences in implementation, implementation != semantics. About differences in object identity; object identity is extremely tangential to the functionality of lambdas; nobody checks the object identity of lambdas/anon classes anyway because it is not useful.

Answer (score 1):

Joachim Sauer already did a good job answering you question but only hinted at something I regard as important. Since Lambdas are no classes they are also not compiled as such. All anonymous inner classes result in the creation of a .class file which in turn has to be loaded by the ClassLoader. So using Lambdas instead does not only make your code more beautiful, it also reduces the size of your compiled code, the memory footprint of your ClassLoader, and the time it takes to transfer the bits from your hard drive.

Answer (score -1):

No. They are not.

Another way to put it is lambdas are an un-object-oriented, however concise, way to achieve the same thing that an anonymous class or, my preference, inner class would achieve in an object-oriented way.

Comment: Functional programming can be totally orthogonal to Object Oriented programming (see: Scala and F#). This reads like the opinion of somebody who simply dislikes functional programming on principle.

Comment: @KChaloux - Not a functional programming hater. The answer is written by someone who prefers to have a hammer AND a screwdriver rather than a Hammerdriver. OO Programming is a good paradigm, as is functional programming. My preference in a language is for it to be clear about its intentions. Lambdas I feel muddy the otherwise OO nature of Java. Java was not designed to be a functional language. Human beings need structure to do their best work.